# How to use tessedit_write_images with pytesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract 0.3.10 with tesseract 5.3.0.
I want to take a look at how tesseract processed my images.
I tried setting tessedit_write_images to true via:

```
import pytesseract as pt
pt.image_to_string(crop_img, lang='eng+deu+fra+spa', config="--psm 6 -c tessedit_write_images=1")
```

But this is not working. The tessinput.tif file is nowhere to be found.
(The `--psm 6` part is working.)

I also tried to use `tessedit_write_images=True` or `tessedit_write_images=T`.
Using `pt.run_and_get_output()` is also not working.

Is there a possibility to set the variable `tessedit_write_images` to true outside my python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "*config*" text file and write into it:

```
tessedit_write_images true
```

Than use the command line: `tesseract Text.png  out.txt config`

This gives you a **text** and a **.tiff file**. If you rename config to config.txt works also in python subprocess:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.run(["tesseract", "Text.png", "out.txt", "config.txt"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

PS: I used tesseract v5.1.0.20220510
leptonica-1.78.0

Comment: Great! But I had to use shell=False for it to work.

Comment: @Svenja K shell=False is more secure, too.